# format command looping

Tags: command-line, batch-file

If I do the below in a batch files of "format.cmd" and run it - 9 times out of 10 it fails. The prompt keeps on looping the command again and again..? Any idea how to fix this?

Command I run:

```
echo y | format D: /V:DATA /Q
```

Output: It puts more spaces after the echo y then the command above? I am thinking that is the problem but I have no idea what it is.

```
C:\Temp\1>echo y   | format D: /V:DATA /Q
C:\Temp\1>echo y   | format D: /V:DATA /Q
C:\Temp\1>echo y   | format D: /V:DATA /Q
C:\Temp\1>echo y   | format D: /V:DATA /Q
C:\Temp\1>echo y   | format D: /V:DATA /Q
C:\Temp\1>echo y   | format D: /V:DATA /Q
C:\Temp\1>echo y   | format D: /V:DATA /Q
C:\Temp\1>echo y   | format D: /V:DATA /Q
C:\Temp\1>echo y   | format D: /V:DATA /Q
C:\Temp\1>echo y   | format D: /V:DATA /Q    
C:\Temp\1>echo y   | format D: /V:DATA /Q
```

continues until I have to kill it.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you post the whole batch script? Is there a loop in it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: yes, please edit your question to include all of your `format.cmd` file AND show exact messages that you are getting. If the 2nd block of your posting is showing the exact messages, please add a heading to it like 'OUTPUT from `format.cmd`. What you show in that 2nd block with `C:\Temp\1>` at the beginning of each line, looks like a shell prompt, which doesn't make sense as a output from a `.cmd` file. Good luck.

Comment: What I posted in the question was the entire script...not too sure what gave the impression I had more to offer? Also the looping in the 2nd block was the output I was getting. The problem was that I should have been using format.com and not just "format" - seems to work fine now.

Comment: FORMAT is probably configured to not take input from piped standard input but directly from user input. Because you are piping your input, format is not getting any user input and gets locked in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to execute the `format.com` file from the `format.cmd` batch file. However, the order of precedence for like-named files is **.cmd** first, then **.com**, so what is happening is that `format.cmd` is running *itself* and not your `format.com`.

Try making `format.cmd` look like this to explicitly call the **.com** version.

```
echo y|format.com D: /V:DATA /Q
```

Comment: The `format` command in the script is calling `format.cmd` **not** because `.cmd` files have precedence over `.exe` executables, but because executable and batch files are searched *in the current directory first* before checking those stored in the `PATH` variable. And the `format` external command is located in `C:\WINDOWS\System32`, and it's `format.com`, not `format.exe`, by the way.

Comment: And the correct precedence order of extensions of executable files (in a broader sense) in Windows is defined by the `PATHEXT` variable, according to which it's `.COM`, then `.EXE`, then `.BAT`, and only *then* `.CMD`.

Comment: thanks all for the responses - it worked with format.com perfectly! Should have though of using the full file name. Many thanks!